# How can I fix this metaclass-borne TypeError?

Tags: python, plugins, typeerror, metaclass

I'm trying to create a simple dynamic plugin system in which plugins inheriting from class `Bot` automatically register themselves on import.

Below is my code thus far.  Please note that I am working from [this](http://effbot.org/zone/metaclass-plugins.htm) short article.

```
import os.path as osp
from glob import glob
from imp import load_source

from twisted.internet import reactor

run = reactor.run
halt = reactor.stop


class Reactor(object):
    _bot_registry = {}

    def __init__(self, botdir):
        map(load_source, *enumerate(glob(osp.join(botdir, '../bots/*.py'))))
        self.bots = {k: v() for k, v in self._bot_registry.iteritems()}


class Bot(object):
    """Base class for Bots"""
    class __metaclass__(type):
        def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict):
            type.__init__(name, bases, dict)
            Reactor._bot_registry[name] = cls

    def _update(self):
        """Run through one scrape/process/respond iteration."""
        pass

    def scrape(self):
        pass

    def process(self):
        pass

    def publish(self):
        pass
```

When importing the code above, I get a TypeError as follows:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-42-dc3963f5e69b> in <module>()
     19 
     20 
---> 21 class Bot(object):
     22     """Base class for Knacki Bots"""
     23     class __metaclass__(type):

<ipython-input-42-dc3963f5e69b> in __init__(cls, name, bases, dict)
     23     class __metaclass__(type):
     24         def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict):
---> 25             type.__init__(name, bases, dict)
     26             Reactor._bot_registry[name] = cls
     27 

TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    descriptor '__init__' requires a 'type' object but received a 'str'
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type.__init__` has the same call signature as your `metaclass.__init__`. The first argument should be `cls`:

```
type.__init__(cls, name, bases, dict)
```

By the way: Never name a variable `dict`, since it shadows the builtin of the same name. I suggest

```
type.__init__(cls, name, bases, clsdict)
```